# Alternating colors with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a text animation in jquery where the letters in each of the lyrics each alternate between red, orange, pink and blue.

I've managed to get the colors to rotate but it also creates a span of my original unedited text above. I'd rather be able to put the text in in the html rather than have lines in the javascript for some other things that I am working on, is there a way to do that?

This is my javascript code.

```js
$('.lyrics').each(function() {
  var letters = $(this).text().split('');
  var colors = ["#e72f14", "#f59f00;", "#ea4591", "#2a94c7"]; // red, yellow, pink, blue
  for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    //this creates a new span with the letters provided above which I don't want
    document.write("<span style='color:" + colors[(i % colors.length)] + ";'>" + letters[i] + " </span>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="lyrics">There is a castle in the clouds<p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a string with the spans and then replace the original text with the new string. Note that to preserve the spaces in the lyric,, I first split the lyric by the spaces to give words and then for each word split into the letters. I then add a space back in to the string to return the sentence.

```js
$('.lyrics').each(function(){
  var words = $(this).text().split(' ');
  var str ='';
  var colors = ["#e72f14","#f59f00;","#ea4591","#2a94c7"]; // red, yellow, pink, blue

  words.forEach(function(word){
     var letters = word.split('');    

     letters.forEach(function(letter,i){
     str += "<span style='color:" + colors[(i % colors.length)] + ";'>" + letter + "</span>";
     })
   str += '&nbsp;';
  })
  $('.lyrics').html(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="lyrics">There is a castle in the clouds<p>
```

Comment: Wow duh! Thanks so much, that's brilliant!

Comment: No - probs - check the answer again - I modified it to preserve the spaces between the words.  I would perhaps suggest alternating the colours on the entire words and if thats what you want - just make the leterrs loigic happen in the words loop.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do. I noticed the spacing was strange and I thought it was my font. Glad you picked up on that and thanl you so much again!

Answer (score 0):

You were almost good :-) The problem is that the natural behaviour of `document.write()` is to insert the given text into the document. Here we want to replace the HTML content of the paragraph. A possible solution would be to replace each letter in the `letters` array in place, merge them back together using `join`, and use `.html()` to update the paragraph :

```js
$('.lyrics').each(function() {
  var letters = $(this).text().split('');
  var colors = ["#e72f14", "#f59f00;", "#ea4591", "#2a94c7"];
  for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    letters[i] = "<span style='color:" + colors[(i % colors.length)] + ";'>" + letters[i] + "</span>";
  }
  $(this).html(letters.join(""));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="lyrics">There is a castle in the clouds<p>
```

Here is how `join` works :

```
["g", "r", "a", "c", "i", "e"].join("") // "gracie"
```

By the way I've replaced `" </span>"` with `"</span>"`.

Comment: Ah brilliant! Thanks so much! I used the first answer but i continued to have joining issues. This is actually quite brilliant.